# Can my employer read my notes if I use their Wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, security, encryption, colornote

I have "Colornote" app in my android device and I'm using that app for many years. I write my passwords and many other personal things. My workplace has wifi and I use it regularly. Often my notes gets synced when I use that wifi.  Can my employer read my notes? Colornote says they use AES encryption.  I don't understand what it means. Many times, I use public wifi too. When I use public wifi, can they read my passwords and personal notes? Also can they read other word and google doc app documents that I have saved in phone and get synced when I'm online?

And if answers of the above questions are yes, will installing and using Norton360 VPN app secure my notes? Thanks.

Comment: If encrypted they won't be able to read it but any network admin worth her or his salt can know exactly what and when any network connected device does.

Comment: @ChanganAuto As far as they can't read it, I don't have any problem if they know what I'm doing on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Wifi by default is encrypted and if your documents are encrypted on top, it will be impossible for anyone to look at them casually.

Wifi traffic is encrypted using WPA (before it was WEP).

> **Types of wireless security protocols**
> Most wireless APs come with the ability to enable one of four wireless encryption standards:
>
> 1. Wired Equivalent Privacy (WEP)
> 2. Wi-Fi Protected Access (WPA)
> 3. WPA2
> 4. WPA3

From [Wireless security: WEP, WPA, WPA2 and WPA3 differences](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/feature/Wireless-encryption-basics-Understanding-WEP-WPA-and-WPA2)

If the documents were being stored on the server, then there could be a possibility of them being hacked.

- But they are not even stored on your works server.
- They are encrypted
- They are going from your phone to ColourNote directly as multiple IP packets, NOT as a file.

Comment: Talking about Wifi's encryption is of no use here. OP already mentioned that they use their device at places where the Wifi is out of their control (workplace, public wifi), therefore one must assume that administrator of the wifi has means to decrypt wifi traffic. The question therefore comes down to "verifying" Colornote developer's claim that the traffic originating from their app is always encrypted with the scheme they have mentioned. This part is missing in your answer.

Comment: @Firelord thanks. After reading this answer,  I thought phone must be doing something like encryption when we use Wifi. Now I understood.

Comment: @Firelord is there any way to verify Colornote's claim that their app is encrypted?

Comment: @ramanujan search for how to sniff traffic originating from Android device. There, the content of the network packets of ColorNote app should be undecipherable because of encryption. If they are in plain-text/readable then they are not encrypted.